# Converting all occurences of 'true' and 'false' to boolean types

Tags: java, serialization

How can I convert all the occurrences of 'true' and 'false' in a String to their respective boolean types?

I have got two Java Maps<String, Object> one of them is templated and another one has got the replacement values

```
 Map<String, Object> replacementValuesMap = new HashMap<>();
 valuesMap.put("dockerIsEnabled", Boolean.valueOf(true));
 valuesMap.put("host.enabled", Boolean.valueOf(false));
 valuesMap.put("host.url", "https://someurl");
         
 Map<String, Object> template = new HashMap<>();
 template.put("image", "docker:1.2");
 template.put("flag", true);
 template.put("download", "{'isEnabled' : '${dockerIsEnabled}'}");
 template.put("hashmap", "externalService: {enabled: '${host.enabled}', host: '${host.url}'}");
```

I am serializing the templated Map first and then using the  StringSubstitutor to replace the place holders in the serialized String.

```
 Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
 String jsonString = gson.toJson(template);

 StringSubstitutor sub = new StringSubstitutor(replacementValuesMap);   
 String resolvedString = sub.replace(jsonString);
```

And at last I have to deserialize the string back into Map<String, Object>

```
 System.out.println( gson.fromJson(resolvedString, HashMap.class));
```

Another question I have here is. Will deserializing a String back into Map<String, Object> will cause boolean types to convert into type String again?

Any other way this can be simplified? I have tried to use snakeyaml to serialize it has same outcome.

Expected Output:

```
{image=docker:1.2, download={'isEnabled' : true}, flag=true, hashmap=externalService: {enabled: false, host: 'https://someurl'}}
```

Actual Output:

```
{image=docker:1.2, download={'isEnabled' : 'true'}, flag=true, hashmap=externalService: {enabled: 'false', host: 'https://someurl'}}
```

Comment: What's your `resolvedString`? Does it contain `'isEnabled' : true` or `'isEnabled' : 'true'`?

Comment: resolvedString has got the unicode charters for single quotes.

{
  "image": "docker:1.2",
  "download": "{\u0027isEnabled\u0027 : \u0027true\u0027}",
  "flag": true,
  "hashmap": "externalService: {enabled: \u0027false\u0027, host: \u0027https://someurl\u0027}"
}

Comment: I tried to serialize the Map with SnakeYaml and then after substituting the values. Replaced all occurrence of single quoted 'true' and 'false' with true and false . Here is the regex expression. The Deserialized map also doesn't have quotes around true and false.

resolvedString.replaceAll("\'\'(false|true)\'\'", "$1")

Output: 

{image: 'docker:1.2', download: '{'isEnabled' :  true }', flag: true,
  hashmap: 'externalService: {enabled: false, host: ''https://someurl''}'}

Not sure if it is graceful. And haven't been able to solve it with Gson.